# how to organize Custom API .js files for Azure Mobile services in folders

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to organize the Custom API .js files for Azure Mobile services in some folder structure? either from the Azure Portal or from Visual Studio 2013?